# why assert(str!=NULL) does not return an error?

Tags: c++, c, assert

**Why did this not print an assert error?**

*This is my code:*

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n =12;
    char str[50] = "";
    assert(n>=10);
    printf("output :%d\n",n);
    assert(str!=NULL);
    printf("output :%s\n",str);
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect `str` to be `NULL`?

Comment: Arrays *decay* to pointers to their first element, so `str` will decay to `&str[0]`. And since arrays can't be empty, all pointers to elements in the array will be valid and definitely non-null.

Comment: Did you mistake this check for `assert(str[0] != '\0');`?

Comment: My ***guess*** is that you confuse the null *pointer* with the null *string terminator character*. They are two different things. `NULL` is a null pointer, while `'\0'` is a string null terminator character. To check if a character is equal to the terminator you need to get that character, like `str[0]`.

Comment: Also, there's *nothing* in the show code that is C++ specific. It's a plain C program.

Comment: Question is tagged as `C++`, but code is valid `C` code (it is not idiomatic `C++`, but compiles fine in `C++`)!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude On one hand yes, but on the other we generally want to know if OP uses a C++ *compiler* or a C *compiler*, so the `c++` tag is correct (not sure if you were arguing with that or not).

Comment: I compile it with C and C++ compiler and still no error, and when i edit it like fabian's comment it still no error

Comment: Is that so? When I edit it like fabian suggested I do get an error https://godbolt.org/z/EfMoPsszW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char str[50] = "";
```

This makes `str` into an array of 50 chars, and initialises the memory to all zeroes (first byte explicitly from `""` and rest implicitly, because C does not support partial initialisation of arrays or structs).

---

```
assert(str!=NULL);
```

When used in an expression, array is treated as pointer to its first element. The first element of the array very much has an address, so it is not `NULL`.

---

If you want to test if the first element of the array is 0, meaning empty string you need

```
assert(str[0] != '\0');
```

You could compare to `0`, or just say `assert(*str);`, but comparing to character literal `'\0'` makes it explicit to the reader of the code, that you are probably testing for string-terminating zero byte, not some other kind of zero, even if for the C compiler they're all the same.

Answer (score -1):

str is an array which is effectively a pointer, which means the address in memory where the array is stored. A pointer is NULL if it doesn't point to any specific place in memory. Your str pointer is not null, it points to a place in memory containing an array of 50 elements.

That array is an array of chars, otherwise known as a string. You initialise it to an empty string but it's still there and the pointer to it (str) is still a valid, non-NULL pointer.

str!=NULL does not mean "str is not an empty string"! It means "str is not an undefined pointer".

Comment: *"which is effectively a pointer"* - No, no, most definitely not. This is the most misleading falsehood novices are taught, and it should be challenged at every turn.

Comment: [An array will decay to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) in most situations, but I disagree with your statement that it "effectively" is a pointer. For example, using the `sizeof` operator on an array has a very different effect than using that operator on a pointer.

Comment: Array types and pointer types are different things. However, array is effectively treated as a pointer except in a handful of situations, like sizeof(). This is described here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf


That's why you can use pointer aritmetic on an array. This may also help:
http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/3300/spr16/Notes/C/Array/pointer.html#:~:text=An%20array%20is%20considered%20to,issue%20of%20using%20an%20array.